# (Jquery)Why .find or .filter return 0 size() object for an ajax html doc response?

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can I get the body or head or whole html from AJAX responsetext (html doc) ?

Here is the response :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/p1_page/style_sheets/p1.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/p1_page/scripts/s1.js" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content_wrapper">
            <table><tr><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td>ala</td></tr><tr><td></td><td><span id="button_wrapper"><span id="button_on" ><input type="hidden" name="" value="1" /></span></span></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td></tr></table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried:

```
$(response).find('body') // returns object with size() 0;  
$(response).filter('body') // returns object of size() 0;  
$('body', response) // returns object of size() 0;
```

But this returns an object of size() 7 - I don't get it?

```
$(response)
```

Comment: if you need just a content within the `body` tag, you can try to remove everything else first by using regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.parseXML()` to convert `string` to a `Document` object:

```
var html = '<html><body>hello, world</body></html>'
$($.parseXML(html)).find('body')
```

Comment: And how will i get the the contents of the body node? with .text() i get only the values of the nodes , w/o the nodes . With .html() i get error that innerhtml is undefined. Is there an innerXML like method?